# Max independent set of a sequence

Tags: c++, c++11, graph, stl

This is the code I've written to find the maximum-weight independent set of a graph path. It's a standard problem with a well-known dynamic programming solution of linear complexity. Since it's a graph path, it's simplified down to a sequence of vertex weights, and we need to find the subset of non-adjacent vertices having the maximum sum.

Basically, it does this:

1. Iterates the sequence forward to calculate max-weight
2. Stores the included vertices in `vector<bool>` of n
3. Iterates the included vertices backwards to reconstruct the max-set
4. (not strictly required) returns the reversed max-set, so it's in original order.

I wonder whether this code could be done more elegantly from the point of STL usage.
Specifically:

1. I'm using `accumulate` with `pair` to keep the previous state, this might be sloppy.
2. There is also a `vector<bool>` that I use to avoid duplicate comparisons when reconstructing the set, maybe this can be done better too.
3. `copy_if` could generate the vertices in the original-order if we had `copy_backward_if`, but we don't.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template<class W>
std::pair<W, std::vector<W>> max_weighted_independent_set(const std::vector<W> &verts)
{
    if (verts.empty())
        return std::make_pair(0, std::vector<W>());
    else if (verts.size() == 1)
        return std::make_pair(verts.front(), std::vector<W>{verts.front()});

    // Dynamic programming approach. The current max-weighted set either
    // excludes the prev vertex or includes it but skips the current one.
    // To pass along the previous weights a pair<prev-prev, prev> is used.
    std::vector<bool> includes(verts.size());
    auto inc = begin(includes); *inc++ = true;
    auto wmax = accumulate(++verts.cbegin(), verts.cend(), std::make_pair(0, verts[0]),
        [&](const std::pair<W, W> &p, const W weight) {
        const W new_weight = p.first + weight; // overflow check omitted for clarity
        return std::make_pair(p.second, (*inc++ = new_weight > p.second) ?
            new_weight : p.second);
    }); 

    // Reconstruct the set by skipping verts according to the includes vector.
    std::vector<W> result;
    auto i = includes.crbegin(); bool skip = false;
    copy_if(verts.crbegin(), verts.crend(), back_inserter(result),
        [&](const W &lhs) { return skip = skip ? i++, false : *i++; });

    // Reversing the copy is redundant and provided for convenience.
    return std::make_pair(wmax.second, std::vector<W>(result.crbegin(), result.crend()));
}

int main() {
    auto result = max_weighted_independent_set(std::vector<int>{1, 4, 5, 4});
    copy(result.second.begin(), result.second.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << "weight: " << result.first << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I've skipped the overflow checking code and unit-tests for brewity. I also ignore negative weights and duplicate max-sets to keep the focus on STL application.